# Functions called in incorrect sequence, or earlier call was unsuccessful (when loading Sound 2nd time)

Tags: actionscript-3

Error  #2037 : Functions called in incorrect sequence, or earlier call was unsuccessful

I get the above error when i call playThatSound() function  2nd or 3rd time.. or so on. ( Not the 1st time )

I am using Flex SDK, using FDT Editor

Code:

```
var sound_Snd:Sound = new Sound() //definition inside the class

function playThatSound():void 
{   
sound_Snd.load( new URLRequest( <pathvalue>)) ;
sound_Snd.play(); 
}
```

However i got rid of this error by redefining sound_Snd as follows :

```
function playThatSound():void 
{
sound_Snd = new Sound(); //redefined everytime when function is called 
sound_Snd.load( new URLRequest( <pathvalue>)) ;
sound_Snd.play(); 
}
```

But, i need to know, what in case i don't want to redefine it again and again, on every function call. Is there something i am missing, when using load and play function for Sound class.

Comment: Are you sure that this is right: `sound_Snd = load(...` ?

Comment: that was a typo.. corrected now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for `Sound.load()` says this:

> Once load() is called on a Sound object, you can't later load a different sound
>       file into that Sound object. To load a different sound file, create a new Sound
>       object.

It also says:

> If you provide a valid URLRequest object to the Sound constructor, the
>       constructor calls Sound.load() for you. You only need to call Sound.load()
>       yourself if you don't pass a valid URLRequest object to the Sound constructor or
>       you pass a null value.

So if you call `load()` explicitly or provide a valid `URLRequest` to the `Sound` constructor, either way, you're resigned to creating a new `Sound` object any time you want to change URLs.

Also I was able to produce this with the same URL being used twice, and I was able to fix it by either creating a new `Sound` object or just not trying to reload the URL, so apparently it doesn't matter if the URL is the same or different.  It would also crash on me whether the same `URLRequest` object were used or not, so you have to either create a new `Sound` object or just not call `load()`.